# Ubuntu 20.04 has no suspend option

Tags: suspend

Greeting...

After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I notice 'Suspend' or 'sleep' option is missing.

Although I can set criteria under 'Power' in settings to enable automatic sleeping, I would like to just click an option to suspend the system.

What do I need to do to bring 'Suspend' to the options on the upper-right corner region?

thanks much,
Ben

Comment: Click on the power off/logoff and you get the suspend choice.

Comment: I have the same problem. any progress on this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2G7I.png

Comment: same problem, no solution...

Answer (score 0):

There should already be a "power" button which has this option included. If you're missing it, re-add it to the panel via options.
[image: Power button Focal Ubuntu]

Comment: How do you "re-add it to the panel via options" ?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that, since I'm on Xubuntu, where you just right click on the panel to customize.  Ubuntu should be similar, but I believe you can simply drag & drop it onto the dock from the menu instead.
Also, you should be able to add items to the dock or panel from the settings menu.
You should be able to add things like the clock, if you've removed it; network activity, calendar, etc.
I assumed you had already customized the "panel" as Ubuntu's generally is on the left side, not the top as you have it. Or, possibly you're using the interface from another desktop UI?